# Attempting to send push notification from my laravel server to expo not working

Tags: laravel, react-native, push-notification, expo

This is the api error that i recieve when i make a post request to expo api:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"API_ERROR","message":"child \"to\" fails because [\"to\" is required], \"value\" must be an
array."}]}
```

This is the request i am trying to make

```
$payload=json_encode([
       'to' => "ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]",
       'title'=>'Hello',
       'body'=>'hello World',


   ]);

     $response = Http::withHeaders([
         'Host'=>'exp.host',
         'accept'=>'application/json',
         'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
         'accept-encoding'=>'grizp,deflate',
     ])->post('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', [
         'debug' => TRUE,
         'body' => $payload,
     ]);
```

but when i  make the api call from my expo app using javascript its works fine

```
  sendPushNotification = async () => {
    const message = {
      to: this.state.expoPushToken,
      sound: 'default',
      title: 'Hello',
      body: 'Hello World',
      data: { data: 'goes here' },
      _displayInForeground: true,
    };

    const response = await fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(message),
    });
  };
```

Comment: try sending `to` as an array like `'to' => ["ExponentPushToken"]`?

Comment: @UzairRiaz unfortunately that did not work ,same error

Answer (score 0):

Change your `$payload` variable to be an array of objects like this:

```
$payload = json_encode([
            [
                'to' => "ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]",
                'title' => 'Hello',
                'body' => 'hello World',
            ]
        ]);
```

Comment: That also did not work for me,Thank you for your suggestions, the problem is when i make the api call from the mobile app  (expo app) it works but when i make the call from the laravel server app it returns the error message

Comment: could you post your payload that you send from your mobile app?

Comment: i edited the question and added the fetch javascript code from my mobile app to it